# How to reorganize my stack panel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stack, panel

I have problems with formating my stack panel and content inside,
I am working on small app for caffe bars lets say, customer is able to choose drink from the middle of screen and 
drink will be shown in the right part of screen in my stack panel, this is how that looks like righw now (when customer choose something - lets say Coke):
[image]

And this is how I would like to make it look a like:[image]

**My code where everything is done:**

```
public DrinksPanel(int id, int groupID, double price,double priceHappyHour, string text, int fontSize, int numberSize, int buttonWidth, int buttonHeight, int margin, Thickness border, byte[] image)
            : base()
        {
            this.Width = buttonWidth+90;
            this.Height = buttonHeight + 35;
            image.Source =  GetImageFromByte(image);

            ID = id;
            groupID = groupID;
            price = price;

            priceHappyHour = priceHappyHour;

            LeftPanelButton.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            LeftPanelButton.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            LeftPanelButton.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            LeftPanelButton.MaxWidth = LeftPanelButton.Width = buttonWidth;
            LeftPanelButton.Height = LeftPanelButton.MaxHeight = this.Height;
            LeftPanelButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

            _image.Width = LeftPanelButton.Width;
            _image.Height = buttonHeight;
            _image.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            _image.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

            PanelQtyNumber.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            PanelQtyNumber.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            PanelQtyNumber.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            PanelQtyNumber.Width = PanelQtyNumber.MaxWidth = this.Width - LeftPanelButton.Width;

            DrinkNameLabel.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            DrinkNameLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            DrinkNameLabel.FontSize = fontSize;

            DrinkNameLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            DrinkNameLabel.MaxWidth = _image.Width; 
            DrinkNameLabel.FontFamily = Util.Font;


            NumberLabel.FontSize = numberSize;
            NumberLabel.Margin = new Thickness(margin, margin, 0, margin);
            NumberLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            NumberLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            NumberLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            NumberLabel.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            NumberLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            NumberLabel.Background = this.Background;

            How to reorganize my stack panel WPF 




            DrinkNameLabel.Content = text;
            NumberLabel.Content = "x1";

            LeftPanelButton.Children.Add(image);
            LeftPanelButton.Children.Add(DrinkNameLabel);
            PanelQtyNumber.Children.Add(NumberLabel);

            Rectangle rct = new Rectangle();
            rct.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
            rct.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            rct.Height = 2;



            _animation = new DoubleAnimation(numberSize, numberSize + 15, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 300)));

            _animation.AutoReverse = true;

            this.Margin = border;
            this.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            StackPanel spNew = new StackPanel();
            spNew.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            spNew.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;

            spNew.Children.Add(LeftPanelButton);
            spNew.Children.Add(PanelQtyNumber);
            StackPanel spNew2 = new StackPanel();
            spNew2.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;

            spNew2.Children.Add(spNew);

            this.Children.Add(spNew2);   
        }
```

***I could not move my text to the right or anyting like that :/ could anyone help me about this please.***

Comment: your problem is that you want a horizontal alignment instead of vertical on your items alignment. But don't do it like that, check for templates and your xaml for the UI not c#...

Comment: change             spNew2.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;

with Horizontal

Comment: Do you have any xaml? Your UI code really shouldn't be set up in C# like that. For this kind of situation you should be using an ItemsControl and data templates in xaml, and an ObservableCollection in your C#.

Comment: @Joe all of xaml I have: <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollerRIGHT" Margin="0,0,0,60" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="stackRIGHT" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

Comment: Where's LeftPanelButton, PanelQtyNumber, DrinkNameLabel, NumberLabel etc in the XAML? You're referencing all these in the C# code.

Comment: @Joe, yes in c# code..

Comment: Why aren't you using XAML??? You are making life difficult for yourself.

Comment: @SledgeHammer noone showed me how to achieve that by xaml, I am in wpf for like 10 days and Im in C# for like 1 year so I find this way easier than XAML

Comment: @Roxy'Pro -- you are wrong :), XAML will reduce that code by about 75% :). Especially once you get into data binding, the more advanced WPF stuff that's "impossible" to do via C#. The way you are doing it will making aligning stuff and handling resizes properly VERY difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Change your LeftPanelButton Orientation is Horizontal then text will move to right side of image.

```
LeftPanelButton.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

If you don't want to the Red color background in your text then remove the LeftPanelButton Background.

NumberLabel set the height and width what ever your want like 80, set the background is your green and foreground is black.

if you still the text is not visible then adjust the width like

```
_image.Width = LeftPanelButton.Width - 100;
```

Comment: I will try it soon, and I will leave you a reply.

Comment: Its Width problem you want adjust your image width based on the requirement
Now I give the ex: _image.Width = LeftPanelButton.Width - 100;